# Using floated DIVs to create two column form layout, unable to clear:right in IE8

Tags: css

I am using the following css to style two column form layout using . I am nable to get it right.

Here's a screenshot of the problem:
[image]

Here is the CSS involved:

```
.editor-label, .display-label{
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    width:160px;
    padding-top:8px;
    display: block;
    clear: left;

}

.editor-field 
{        
    padding-top: 8px;
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    width: 300px;
    display: block;           
}
```

The HTML is rather simple:

```
  <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="UserIdentitiy">*User Name</label>
  </div>

  <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please provide a user name." id="UserIdentitiy" name="UserIdentitiy" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserIdentitiy" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="SS">Social Security</label>
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="SS" name="SS" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="SS" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

As form layouts have been done to death, they're really a solved problem. Instead of fighting, I'd recommend looking at existing solutions, such as the [brilliant semantic markup](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/wiki/7.1-Example-Rendered-HTML) patterns found in [Formastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic).

If you feel compelled to solve it yourself, though, you would have an easier time if you reorganised your markup a little:

```
<div class="form-field">
    <label for="UserIdentitiy">*User Name</label>
    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please provide a user name." id="UserIdentitiy" name="UserIdentitiy" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserIdentitiy" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-field">
    <label for="SS">Social Security</label>
    <input class="text-box single-line" id="SS" name="SS" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="SS" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.form-field {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}

.form-field label {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.form-field .single-line {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 300px;
}
```

This way you have a block scope for each "row" of your form, and the labels are more closely tied with their respective input field and errors.

Comment: +1 - although I want the points, I think this is the best answer!

Comment: I'm using the template generated by Microsoft's MVC3 - as much as I want to re-structure, I don't think it's possible. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a container around each label/input group and give the container a width.

```
.field-container{width:460px}
```

html

```
<div class="field-container">
      <div class="editor-label">
          <label for="UserIdentitiy">*User Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
          <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please provide a user name." id="UserIdentitiy" name="UserIdentitiy" type="text" value="" />
          <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserIdentitiy" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eqeB6/3/